# NetBSD 5.1 NDIS Kernel Compile Error

Tags: kernel, networking, compiling, wifi, netbsd

I have an old Toshiba Satellite 4015CDT, with Pentium II MMX, 32MB RAM, 4GB HDD. It also has one USB 1.0 port, parallel and serial ports, a 3.5" floppy drive and a CD-ROM drive (almost dead). I've installed NetBSD on this machine (full install) and now I want to connect it to the Internet. Although it has one PCMCIA modem card in it, it is obviously not an option.

In order to do that I tried to connect my Realtek RTL8192U wireless adapter, but although the system gives me the device's name (through dmesg) it fails to recognize it as a network adapter. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ndis&manpath=NetBSD+5.1) and [here](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/kernel/) to recompile the kernel with NDIS support (I gave this configuration the name "NDIS"). At compile time I got the following error messages:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
../../../../dev/if_ndis/if_ndis.c: In function 'ndis_detach':
../../../../dev/if_ndis/if_ndis.c:1187: warning: passing argument 1 of 'mutex_destroy' from incompatible pointer type
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/sys/arch/i386/compile/NDIS
```

I would very much appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks in advance.

P.S. If it is of any help, the system was installed by first booting off the installation floppies ("boot1.fs" and "boot2.fs" downloaded from the [official ftp server](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-5.1/i386/installation/floppy/)), and then the packages were copied from a USB flash drive (packages also downloaded from the [ftp server](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-5.1/i386/binary/sets/)).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `-Werror` option which is passed to `gcc` somewhere in the Makefile.

The warning will then be merely considered as a warning and won't interrupt the compilation process.